# Sticky header slide down effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
         var sticky = $('.top-menu'),
         scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 200){
            sticky.addClass('fixed');
        }else{
            sticky.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
```

Fixed css

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

It works fine, but i want a 'slide down of the top effect' can i do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: can you please post the relative html too?

Answer (score 4):

For smooth slide down animation you can try following things:

JS Code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
         var sticky = $('.top-menu'),
         scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 200){
            sticky.addClass('fixed');
            sticky.slideDown(1000);
        }else{
            sticky.removeClass('fixed');
            sticky.removeAttr("style"); //slideDown adds the style="block" which needs to be removed so that next time slideDown will work
        }
    });
```

CSS Code:

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    display:none;
}
```

Here logic is; to add 'fixed' class after 200px scroll. At this moment `sticky` will be `display:none` via added CSS class. Then slide it down to make it visible. If user scrolls up and goes below 200px then remove `fixed` class and remove `style` attribute added to `sticky` via `slideDown()` function. Hope this will help. I tried it and its working perfectly like [www.walmart.com](http://www.walmart.com)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into CSS transition and transform properties.

- Transition will control how quickly an object animates.
- Transform will control the transformation of the object. (i.e. height from 0 - 100px)

A good resource for learning about CSS3 is [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/) and you should just run through the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much into css stuff but still I guess this might work:

```
       if (scroll >= 200){
             sticky.slideDown();
            sticky.addClass('fixed');
        }else{

            sticky.slideUp();
            sticky.removeClass('fixed');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding code like this so you don't have to specify a height in pixels:

```
var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;

function onScroll(e) {
  window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? sticky.classList.add('fixed') :
                                  sticky.classList.remove('fixed');
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```